# Meaning of the word "enquested"

Tags: meaning

I am looking for the meaning of the word "enquested". I would like to use it in the context of "you were given a quest" or "somebody made you quest something" (with or without your explicit intent).

An example: "Frodo was enquested by Gandalf." or "I am enquested." (i.e. I was given a quest.)

I [made a search on the Google](https://www.google.hu/search?safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=%22enquested%22&oq=%22enquested%22) and the word is not used anywhere.

I created the word by following the following logic:

1. There is the word ["quest"](https://www.google.hu/search?safe=off&q=quest+meaning) which means: "a long or arduous search for something" or "search for; seek out".
2. There is [the "en" prefix](https://www.google.hu/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=meaning%20of%20%22en%22%20prefix) which means

   > "a prefix occurring originally in loanwords from French and productive in English on this model, forming verbs with the general sense “to cause (a person or thing) to be in” the place, condition, or state named by the stem; more specifically, “to confine in or place on” ( enshrine; enthrone; entomb); “to cause to be in” ( enslave; entrust; enrich; encourage; endear); “to restrict” in the manner named by the stem, typically with the additional sense “on all sides, completely” ( enwind; encircle; enclose; entwine). This prefix is also attached to verbs in order to make them transitive, or to give them a transitive marker if they are already transitive ( enkindle; enliven; enshield; enface)."
3. The "ed" is just the past tense which means that it already happened or you can use it in passive mode.

I have another issue with the word (besides that it is not found by Google). [According to Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enquest) enquest is another/older form of [inquest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquest). I do not want to use the word in the sense of law.

I have found one occurrence of the word enquest [here](https://www.google.hu/search?safe=off&q=%22enquests+and+adventures%22), but I cannot understand its meaning clearly:

> The Birth Life and Acts of King Arthur, of His Noble Knights of the Round Table, Their Marevllous **Enquests** and Adventures, the Achieving of the San Greal and in the End Le Morte Darthur with the Dolourous Death and Departing out of This World of Them All

My questions:

1. Is the word "enquested" exists?
2. Is the meaning of the word "you were given a quest" or something similar?
3. Is it easy to mix it with the word "inquest"? Do you thing for the same when you read the word "enquest"? Do you have a feel that "enquested" is a law related thing?
4. What is the difference between the words "enquested" and "enquestened"?

Comment: As others have pointed out this is a made up word. Fantasy words are off-topic. If you want to use made up words, head over to Worldbuilding or Writers SE. I am voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about genuine English.

Comment: @Helamr What happened to your close-vote?

Comment: enquested is not in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=enquested&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch).  Enquest is in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/96492?redirectedFrom=enquest#eid) as an old form of inquest.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such word, as you have surely figured out by now.  That King Arthur quote is full of lots of spelling errors and doesn't count.

Given that it doesn't exist, questions 2 and 4 are irrelevant.

As for question 3, people might guess the intended meaning with sufficient contextual clues, but I'd recommend sticking to the English language rather than making your own words up.

Finally, a word for giving someone a quest:  you could say that they were *"entrusted with a quest"* (or entrusted with the Ring in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The documents got from [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enquest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenquest%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cenquest%3B%2Cc1) show that the word *enquest* is mainly used in the sense of **investigation**. "Enquest" was used in old french in that inquiry sense which is kept in its new french ortograph "Enquête" (*a standard French language evolution where the "s" was replaced by a circumflex accent on the "e" in the 16th-17th centuries*).

In Sir Thomas Malory's (c. 1415-18 – 14 March 1471) famed "Morte d’Arthur"/ book Thirteen describing Sir Gawaine’s quest for the Holy Grail, the chapter 7 title is:

> How the Queen Desired to See Galahad [*Lancelot's son by Elaine*]; and How After, All the Knights
>   Were Replenished with the Holy Sangreal, and How They Avowed the
>   Enquest of the Same.

In the above title, "Enquest" seems to be used in the sense of **quest**, that for the Holy Grail.

Comment: Presumably that's the same word that became *inquest* in English.